# Hyphenation of terms containing symbols other than letters

Tags: hyphenation, mhchem

I'm trying to hyphenate a chemical name and have come into difficulty. The word I'm trying to hyphenate is *poly(ethyeneglycol)*.

I'm using `babel` and `inputenc`. I've tried specifying a custom hyphenation pattern using `\hyphenation{poly(ethylene-glycol)}` but it fails to complete.

Being chemistry terminology I wondered if this was dealt with by a chemistry package such as `mhchem` but have not found a package that does it.

Comment: I have noticed all your words "hyphenate" were missing the h, including the command `\hyphenation{poly(ethylene-glycol)}`. I corrected them all in your question, but perhaps your code needs to be corrected as well? Maybe is just a misspelling problem?

Comment: Have you looked at `bpchem` and the `\IUPAC` macro?

Comment: Hi Joseph, the IUPAC macro didn't seem to do anything to it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Techically, `(` and `)` are not letters, so they won't participate to hyphenation. You can make them acceptable with the following trick, which should have no adverse effect with normal input:

```
\lccode`\(=`\(
\lccode`\)=`\) 
\hyphenation{poly(ethylene-glycol)}
```

A different strategy could be to define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\Q}[1]{(\nobreak\hspace{0pt}#1)}
\hyphenation{ethylene-glycol} % TeX incorrectly hyphenates this word
```

and use

```
poly\Q{ethyleneglycol}
```