# hyphenation with special (Estonian) letters

Tags: hyphenation, accents

Hyphenation is working correctly most of the time, but it has problems with words that have Estonian letters like õ inside of the word. For example:

```
lõplikumõõtmeline.
```

I write it like this in TeX:

```
l~oplikum~o~otmeline.
```

LaTeX refuses to hyphenate this word. From output:

> LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
>   Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
>   yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
>   erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
>    french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
>   us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
>   tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish,
>   turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
>
> ...
>
> Overfull \hbox (33.50668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 969--970
>   []\T1/cmr/m/n/12 Eelneva n�i-te p[]ohjal si-sal-dab te-ki-ta-tud ope-raa-to-ri-
>   deaal k[]oik l[]oplikum[]o[]otmelised|

I tried to search, but I only found such links, that did not help much:

1. [Hyphenation of terms containing symbols other than letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59722/hyphenation-of-terms-containing-symbols-other-than-letters)
2. [Hyphenation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60237/hyphenation-in-latex)
3. [pdflatex and \hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/pdflatex-and-hyphenation)

I tried to do like this:

```
\hyphenation{l~op-li-ku-m~o~ot-me-line}
```

But I got error:

> ! Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. \leavevmode ->\unhbox
>                         \voidb@x l.54 \hyphenation{l~
>                       op-li-ku-m~o~ot-me-line}

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my configuration:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
```

EDIT2:

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teoreem}{Teoreem}
\newtheorem{lause}[teoreem]{Lause}
\newtheorem{jareldus}[teoreem]{J\"areldus}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defin}{Definitsioon}


\newenvironment{toestus}{\begin{proof}[T~oestus]}{\end{proof}}


\author{Rauni Lillemets}
\begin{document}

\begin{lause}
Olgu $1 \leq p \leq \infty, 1 \leq r \leq p^*$. 
\end{lause}
\begin{toestus}
Eelneva n"aite p~ohjal sisaldab tekitatud operaatorideaal k~oik l~oplikum~o~otmelised operaatorid.
\end{toestus}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no overfull box with this example and the word is hyphenated as "lõplikumõõt-melised"

Comment: The problem might be in the fact that you are running an old TeX distribution, that still hasn't complete hyphenation patterns for Estonian.

Comment: Watch the date (LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>). How old is your LaTeX installation!

Comment: Yeah, well, the question is also 5 years old. But I agree that the installation was old already then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\parbox{1pt}{\hspace{0pt}
  l~oplikum~o~otmeline
}
\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` is just to show all hyphenation points.

[image]

If I run your example, I get what follows (after removing the blank line before `\end{toestus}`:

[image]

The same if I run `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2007 and later versions. However, I get the problem with hyphenation in older TeX distribution if the input is given with direct typing of accented characters (in UTF-8 encoding): if I type

```
\begin{toestus}
Eelneva näite põhjal sisaldab tekitatud operaatorideaal kõik lõplikumõõtmelised operaatorid.
\end{toestus}
```

adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, I indeed get

[image]

However, if I run the same with TeX Live 2009, the hyphenation is correct.

Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Sorry, but I already have these two rows in beginning of file. I now posted the package list I have included.

Comment: @Rauni Please add also an example of the paragraph where things go wrong. My code shows that the word *is* hyphenated.

Comment: Added the example. I will be away for some time now, so don't please mind if I don't answer or accept Your answer very soon.